# Using FirewallException api in Wix to apply setting to all network profiles in Win7

Tags: wix, windows-firewall-api

An installer with wix I've made uses the FirewallException api to register some components of the package with the Windows firewall, in order to try and prevent firewall popups.

It seems that in Windows7, it only registers with exception for the network profile (ie Work/Home/Private) that is currently active when the user runs the installer. When the user changes network profile, and runs our application, they are presented with firewall popups.

Can we use the firewall exception to apply the settings to all Network Profiles? The syntax I'm currently using is:

```
<fire:FirewallException Id="XXXX" Name="Program Name" Scope="any" File="WixFileRef"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code didn't come through but you can control the profile(s) used using the Profile attribute. It's available in WiX v3.5 and later.